# How can you make a parent process display PID of child instead of value variable?

Tags: linux, process, pid

In linux how can I make a parent process display the PID of a child process rather than the value variable?

Comment: In which language? `bash` or `C` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch C Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chance to get the child PID is while you fork.

Python:

```py
import os

child_pid = os.fork()
if child_pid == 0:
    print "This is the child, my pid is", os.getpid()
else:
    print "This is the parent, my child pid is", child_pid
```

C:

```c
pid_t child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == 0) {
    printf("This is the child, my pid is %d\n", getpid());
}
else {
    printf("This is the parent, my child pid is %d\n", child_pid);
}
```